# Test functional route resolver

Tags: angular, jestjs

Class based route resolvers have been recently deprecated in Angular in favor of functional resolvers. See the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/router/ResolveFn).

Does anyone have examples of unit testing these functional resolvers?

I'm not finding any examples in the Angular docs, and the Angular test environment is difficult to configure. So for example, how would one unit test the example function in the docs?

```
export const heroResolver: ResolveFn<Hero> =
    (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
      return inject(HeroService).getHero(route.paramMap.get('id')!);
    };
```

I'm using a resolver that's basically identical to this in that it calls some service to fetch an entity by ID. When trying to configure call the resolver in Jest, I get the following error:

```
NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a problem I struggled with myself and couldn't let go of until I found the solution, which I am happy to present to you now ;)

I found what I was looking for in this excellent article by Netanel Basel, titled *Testing DI Functions in Angular*: https://netbasal.com/testing-di-functions-in-angular-37a5e7ed75f9.

The API you want is `TestBed.runInInjectionContext()` and was released in Angular `15.1`, so very recent stuff.

Assuming getHero() returns an observable, the solution is as follows:

```
it('should call getHero()', (done) => {
    TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => heroResolver(routeMock, stateMock)).subscribe(() => {            
        expect(heroServiceMock.getHero).toHaveBeenCalledWith(routeMock.paramMap['id']);
        done();
    });
});
```

I'm not testing for what `getHero()` returns here, which is probably what you'd want to add for your specific case. `routeMock` and `stateMock` are mocks you have to set up and populate for your test cases.

Hoping this helps!

Comment: what if we need to inject another couple of services in the body of functional resolver?

Comment: I ended up creating mock Router configuration with test target functional guard and used router.navigate to trigger calling guard function.

Answer (score 1):

Any services that need to be mocked for the functional resolver must be provided when you configure the `TestBed`. Here is an example that uses the `TestBed.runInInjectionContext()` API:

Assume that we have a functional resolver that fetches a `Task` in a To-Do app:

```typescript
// imports are omitted for brevity

export const taskDetailsResolver: ResolveFn<Task> = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  _state: RouterStateSnapshot
) => {
  const store = inject(Store); // NgRx
  const router = inject(Router);
  const thisRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  const taskId = parseInt(route.paramMap.get('taskId')!);

  return inject(TasksService)
    .get(taskId)
    .pipe(
      tap((task) => store.dispatch(MyRestApiActions.loadTaskSuccess({ task }))),
      catchError((error: ApiErrorResponse) => {        
        store.dispatch(MyRestApiActions.loadTaskError({ error }));
        router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: thisRoute });
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
};
```

Here is one example of a unit test:

```typescript
// imports omitted for brevity

describe('TaskDetailsResolver', () => {
  let router: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;
  let route: jasmine.SpyObj<ActivatedRoute>;
  let httpClient: jasmine.SpyObj<HttpClient>;
  let service: TasksService;
  let store: MockStore;

  beforeEach(() => {
    router = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);
    route = jasmine.createSpyObj('ActivatedRoute', ['']);
    httpClient = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
    service = new TasksService(httpClient);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        provideMockStore(),
        { provide: Router, useValue: router },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: route },
        { provide: HttpClient, useValue: httpClient },
        TasksService,
      ],
    });

    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
  });

  it('should return a task', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const task: Task = { id: 1, title: 'Task 1', projectId: 1 };
    httpClient.get.and.returnValue(of(task));

    const routeStub = {
      paramMap: {
        get: (_key: string) => '1',
      },
    };
    const stateStub = {};

    TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => {
      const result = taskDetailsResolver(
        routeStub as ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        stateStub as RouterStateSnapshot
      );

      if (result instanceof Observable) {
        result.subscribe((task) => {
          expect(task).toEqual(task);
          expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            MyRestApiActions.loadTaskSuccess({ task })
          );

          done();
        });
      } else {
        fail('taskDetailsResolver did not return an Observable');
      }
    });
  });
});
```